# How to add pagination to comments?

Tags: comments, pagination

I am using wp_list_comments(); function to list all the comments, but I want to add some pagination, for example 10 on one page.

I tried "Break comments into pages..." in Discussion panel but it sorts them werid...

Also I have added paginate_comments_links() but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi David.. Without a shadow of doubt my part, this question will get either put on hold, downvoted or flagged in some other way.

I'm going to give you alink to read about how WPSE works, I found it very interesting, especially the answer from Rarst.

http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/how-should-i-word-my-previous-question

Comment: The codex already provide pagination args for comments? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Answer (score 2):

Put below code into your current theme's **comments.php** file:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?> 
</div>

<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
</ol>

<div class="navigation">
    <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?> 
</div>
```

This code will display pagination as you expect. Don't forgot to check the break comment to part with number of settings from `Admin > Settings > Discussion Settings`. See below example snap.

[image]

I tested this code and this should work for you also. You can check more detail about paginate_comments_links [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/paginate_comments_links).